# Criar item em outro projeto Visual studio 2013 Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, arquitetura-de-software, template

Estou criando um template no visual studio, porém quero que ao adicionar um item em um projeto o mesmo seja criado em todos os outros projetos da solution, alguém pode me ajudar? o código é mais ou menos esse:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
      <TemplateData>
        <DefaultName>WebApiConsulta.cs</DefaultName>
        <Name>WebApiConsulta</Name>
        <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
      </TemplateData>
      <TemplateContent>
        <References />
        <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="Projeto1/$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">ConsultaGrupoProjeto.cs</ProjectItem>
   <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="Projeto2/$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">ConsultaGrupoProjeto.cs</ProjectItem>
   <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="Projeto3/$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">ConsultaGrupoProjeto.cs</ProjectItem>
      </TemplateContent>
    </VSTemplate>
```

Comment: O NuGet eh uma boa ferramenta para fazer este trabalho, de uma lida https://www.nuget.org/

Comment: acho que vc se confundiu amigo, o nuget contém uma série de "plugins" pro visual studio.. vc sabe o nome desse que vc me indicou?

Comment: Voce pode fazer o seu prorpio pacote com o NuGet e adiciona-lo em todos os seus projetos, sempre quando voce atualizar o NuGet irá atualizar todos os seus projetos.. Leia

Comment: Igor, você quer adicionar um ícone ou uma imagem em todos os projetos? Pode exemplificar melhor, por favor?

Comment: oi brandão obrigado pela mensagem, na verdade eu quero incluir um arquivo padrão pra ser usado como "template" para os desenvolvedores aqui da minha equipe.O visual studio da a opção de exportar item e projeto, quando é usado o projeto exportado ele aquiva criando um "projeto" padrão. Quando é item ele pode criar uma serie de arquivos em um mesmo projeto. minha intenção que mesmo com os projetos ja criados eu consiga "caminhar" entre os projetos e incluir meu template em cada pasta específica de cada projeto. parece complexo mas é simples e minha equipe iria ganhar um bom tempo em produção.

Comment: essa imagem acima é somente o icone que é mostrado no template.

Comment: Acho que o melhor seria cria uma extensão do visual studio para fazer isso.

Comment: o template já é uma espécie de extensão..

Comment: Digo uma extensão do tipo VSPackage. ex:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966591.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente isto que você precisa, mas no tutorial abaixo a autora mostra como criar um template de múltiplos projetos, assim quando você cria a solution utilizando o template criado todos os projetos do template já são incluídos.

Fonte: http://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/

Espero que seja isso.

Comment: realmente ajuda bastante, deixei uma mensagem pra ela quando encontrei o blog dela faz mais ou menos uns 3 meses. A opçãio que tive pra esse problema foi fazwer um template pra cada projeto. antes eu usei macros mas o visual studio 2013 nao permite mais macros. Obrigado.